# Extracting a specific string from a column based on other column using SQL in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns in a table. Both are `nvarchar` of different lengths, let's say first columns contains the color (representing a country) and other column contains the country name  with other text e.g

```
Color      text 
green      choosen country: UNITED STATES *some text no fixed length upto 1000 chars*
black      chossen country: S AFRICA *some text no fixed length upto 1000 chars*
red        choosen country: INDIA *some text no fixed length upto 1000 chars*
```

Now I want color and the country name concatenated in my output, as

```
green,UNITED STATES
black,S AFRICA
red,INDIA
```

Comment: Just replace `choosen country: ` with an empty string whenever you select `text`?

Comment: is the text column format fixed? i.e is `choosen country:` always present?

Comment: hi Vkp, Yes choosen country always present

Comment: hi DigiFriend , How do I replace the text after the country name ?

Comment: Is * the separator after that uppercase country name?  If not, how to know where the text is no longer part of the country name?

Comment: no * is not a separator

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the country name as from your example:

```
select stuff(text, 1, charindex(': ', text + ': ') + 2, '') as country_name
```

You can concatenate anything else you want as:

```
select color + ',' + stuff(text, 1, charindex(': ', text + ': ') + 2, '') as country_name
```

Comment: HI Gordon, I have changed  the question little bit  there is some text after country name as well